# How to drag and drop one column from one gridView to another gridview in Windows forms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to drag and drop one column from one grid view to another grid view in Windows forms using C#.Net.Here for designation column in `DataGridview2` has to need to drag and drop in `DataGridview1`

[image: preview image]

Kindly provide your Valuable suggestions to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Use column event handler.  See example in this posting : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/025850a4-d1e3-4750-a1e2-23f4ea074c49/datagridview-drag-drop-column-doesnt-update-datatable?forum=winforms

Comment: what part of your code are you stuck with ?

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestion,but Your given link explain like is with in the grid view their changing the columns.But my case has designation column in DataGridview2 has to need to drag and drop in DataGridview1.